# oracle sql pairing up elements from collections

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, types

i have created 2 types and a table that contains those:

```
create or replace type a_t as varray(5) of int
create or replace type b_t as varray(5) of int

create table test(
  a a_t,
  b b_t
)

insert into test Values (
  a_t(1,2,3),
  b_t(4,5,6)
)
```

what i want now is to select with a result of

```
 a_t     b_t
------|-----
  1   | 4
  2   | 5
  3   | 6
```

using the table operator on 1 column result in :

```
select a.* from test t, table(t.a_t) a

 a_t    
------
  1   
  2   
  3
```

but now i dont know how to get the second row and pair them up in the right order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like This.

```
WITH tab_a
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM rn,
                a.*
         FROM   test t,
                TABLE ( t.a ) a),
     tab_b
     AS (SELECT ROWNUM rn,
                b.*
         FROM   test t,
                TABLE ( t.b ) b)
SELECT a.column_value a_t,
       b.column_value b_t
FROM   tab_a a
       FULL OUTER JOIN  tab_b b
         ON a.rn = b.rn;
```

Comment: This seems to work (similar questions had similar answers on OTN), but it relies on the TABLE function spitting out the array values IN ORDER. It is logical for it to do so, but I haven't been able to confirm this in the documentation. (It is also possible, for example, that the values would be spit out in REVERSE order...) What is probably true is that you can't access the array indices directly in SQL, as you could in PL/SQL. My point being, can we **rely** on the TABLE function behaving this way? Or are there (or will there in the future be) cases when it does something else?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `WITH FUNCTION` (Oracle 12c):

```
WITH FUNCTION f1(i INT, s a_t) RETURN INT AS BEGIN RETURN s(i); END;
     FUNCTION f2(i INT, s b_t) RETURN INT AS BEGIN RETURN s(i); END;
SELECT s.*
FROM test t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT f1(1, t.a) AS a_t   ,f2(1, t.b) AS b_t  FROM dual
             UNION ALL SELECT f1(2, t.a),f2(2, t.b)         FROM dual
             UNION ALL SELECT f1(3, t.a),f2(3, t.b)         FROM dual)s;
```

Output:

```
A_T B_T
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=77cb502fb3ef0a8e122bb89705ac83cc)**